# Ajax refresh in mvc div data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a MVC application, where I have a scenario to refresh a part of the page basically ajax...

```
 <div id="ajax" style="width:10%;float:left">     
 @foreach (var item in @Model.SModel.Where(x=>x.StudentId==13))
 {      
    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(score => item.StudentName)</li> 
 }
```

This is the div (part of the page) which I need to refresh on a button click. I have 2 js files, `data.js` and `render.js`...

**data.js** contains a template as follows:

```
makeAJAXCall = 

function (url, params, callback) {

  $.ajax({


            type: "get",
            timeout: 180000,
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {

                if (callback) {

                    callback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {

                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    };


    getGrid = function () {
        makeAJAXCall(urlCollection["getGridInfo"], "", function (result) {

            renderer.renderGridInfo('ajax', result);

        });
    };
```

and **render.js** file is as follows:

```
renderGridInfo = function (area, data) {

    $("#" + area).text(data);
};


return {
    renderGridInfo: renderGridInfo
};
```

In the **loading page on button click** function as :

```
Service.addURL('getGridInfo', '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("getGridInfo", "AjaxController"))');

        Service.getGrid();
```

In the **ajax controller**, the code is :

```
public JsonResult getGridInfo() 
{ 
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

But the problem I am facing is,   the controller is returning the JsonResult , but the `'div'` accepts the model  and so the  output is `[object] [object] button click`

**Question**:  Is there any way to refresh this `'div'` from the Jsondata returned by the controller?

I have to follow this type of design without using AjaxForm.

Comment: Placing an object into the DOM tends to result in [Object, Object], as only strings or elements are valid.

Comment: have to parse the json to html, unless there is a property within it that contains html you want, then locate that property first

Comment: But how will i pass the html data to 
   the div which uses model data for processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look what happens:

1) you returns **Json**: `return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
2) you put returned Json object to the div's value: `$("#" + area).text(data);`

that's why you end up with json's representation inside div

You need to change it as follows:
1) assume you put html for that div to model's field called *NewHtml*
2) eptract html from the property of returned json: `var returnedHtml = data.NewHtml;`
3) use `html()` method instead of `text()`: `$("#" + area).html(returnedHtml);`